# SCIM and ASP.NET Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-membership, scim

I am exposing an application with RESTful APIs, and one interest I want to pursue is standards alignment. So therefore I am interested in SCIM for user identity functions. What confuses me is:

- SCIM give me an interface to manage user accounts, but not the underlying implementation.
- ASP.NET Membership gives me the implementation (i.e. the actual database where user identities and passwords will be written).

So how do the two link? i.e. I want to use SCIM, but I also want to leverage the off-the-shelf implementation that writes to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is some overlap between [ASP.NET Membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) and SCIM.

But you have it about right.

SCIM provides an abstraction so that the underlying resource management implementation is transparent.

The underlying implementation could be LDAP or a database or any storage facility that can Create, Read, Update, and Delete the underlying Resources.

-jim